# Is there a memory leak in this code

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

If I have a class with constructor that takes an array like this:

```
    public struct MyStruct{
    Car car;
    Boolean processed;
}

public class MyClass{
    private MyStruct[] mCarStructs;

    public MyClass(Car[] cars)
    {
        //So the only reason I pass Car[] in is to use it to
        //populate my array of structs
        mCarStructs = new MyStruct[cars.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < cars.Length; i++)
        {
            myCarStructs[i].car = cars[i];
            myCarStructs[i].processed = false;
        }
    }

    public void processCar(...)
    {
        if (DoProcess(myCarStructs[i].car))
        {
            myCarStructs[i].processed = true;
        }
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

My understanding is that arrays are passed in by default as a reference.  So, I dont think this is a leak and the reference passed in constructor will be nulled once constructor code completes.

So, there is no leak.  Is this correct?

Thanks,

Comment: Mutable structs are evil, you should be avoiding them at all costs.  Also note that the type you have is not a logical representation of a value, and so shouldn't be a `struct` at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays are not *passed* by reference, arrays *are* references.  The reference to the array is passed by value.

As for memory leaks, the Garbage Collector is going to clean up all managed objects as soon as there are no longer any references to those objects; you don't need to worry about explicit memory management except in those cases where you're dealing with unmanaged memory (which you're not doing here).

Comment: Much appreciated Servy